# Unable to install packages in virtual environment VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I'm trying to install packages in a newly created virtual environment in VS Code. The environment is created and selected (highlighted in red in the below image) but `pip` is installing packages in the global environment instead:

[image]

Looking at other questions on SO, most were because the global environment/interpreter were selected instead of the (newly created) virtual environment.

Do I need to "activate" the environment separately? VS Code documentation doesn't mention this and I'm assuming it is automatically activated at creation.

Comment: that terminal doesn't look like it's activated the environment. And no, when you create an environment, it isn't automatically activated, and even if it were, virtual environment activation needs to happen in the shell you are using. Typically, vscode will activate a virtual environment when it creates a new terminal shell, but it's hard to say what is going on here and why, but it seems the environment is definitely not activated

Comment: I guess you are on powershell, not sure what the best equivalent of `which` is, seems like it might be `Get-Command` ... what does that return for `python` and `pip`?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the .venv wasn't activated. Took some time to resolve - the issue was due to Microsoft policy related to remote scripts. I was able to change that in PowerShell which got it working.

Comment: Hi Gautam, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to install packages in your environment you need to first activate it. To activate it you can use the command in the terminal: `.venv\Scripts\activate`

You know it worked if there is a `(.venv)` at the start of the path in the terminal.

If you want more information you can check the guide on [how to install packages in virtual environment using pip and venv](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Hopefully this helps solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively easy way to do this is:

1. Use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose your venv environment as the current python interpreter.
2. Click the `Run Python File` button on the top right. VSCode will active the venv environment for you automatically.
3. Use `pip install packageName` command in the terminal.

Hope this can help.